# What's the purpose of the --class option in grubs menuentry?

Tags: linux, boot, grub2, dual-boot

Why would I want to add a class to my menuentry (in grub2)?

If I understand the [grub manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#menuentry) correctly, it could be used with themes.. But is that all?

Answer (score 3):

In looking through the manual it only seems to pertain to theming. This excerpt had a bit more on the subject.

*excerpt - http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#menuentry*

> The boot menu where GRUB displays the menu entries from the “grub.cfg”
>   file. It is a list of items, where each item has a title and an
>   optional icon. The icon is selected based on the *classes* specified
>   for the menu entry. If there is a PNG file named “myclass.png” in the
>   “grub/themes/icons” directory, it will be displayed for items which
>   have the class *myclass*. The boot menu can be customized in several
>   ways, such as the font and color used for the menu entry title, and by
>   specifying styled boxes for the menu itself and for the selected item
>   highlight.

Answer (score 2):

Found this for [menuentry](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/menuentry.html):

The --class option may be used any number of times to group menu entries into classes. Menu themes may display different classes using different styles.

You need to look at [grub-themes](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Theme-file-format) for usage.

---

Other options:
The --users option grants specific users access to specific menu entries. See Security.

The --unrestricted option grants all users access to specific menu entries. See Security.

The --hotkey option associates a hotkey with a menu entry. key may be a single letter, or one of the aliases ‘backspace’, ‘tab’, or ‘delete’